# Executing msg.exe from Visual Basic application

Tags: vb.net, cmd

I am trying to take text fields for old hostname, new hostname, username, and password and remotely change computer names. That part is working fantastic. It was all great until my manager saw it in action, since we have a policy against downloading and using freeware.

It's not freeware if I made it. Unfortunately, he sent it to my director, and know my director knows I know a little bit about Visual Basic, so he wants to loop the names from a CSV file, change the name, and send a message to the end user instructing them to save their files and reboot.

Unfortunately, net send has gone the way of XP since Vista. However, from Vista - Win8.1, there's a utility called msg.exe in C:\Windows\System32. In order to use it, the target computer has to have the registry value AllowRemoteRPC in HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Services set to 1.

So here's what the app does:

Reads the DWORD key AllowRemoteRPC and stores it to a variable (MyVal), changes the key to 1, attempts to send the message alerting the user they need to restart, changes the key back to MyVal, and then executes netdom renamecomputer and renames the PC. Everything works perfectly EXCEPT sending the message. I can open up a command prompt and type:

```
msg /server:hostname * /v /time:3600 "my message here
```

And it works perfectly (after manually editing the registry key to the needed value).

However, running it from VB doesn't work. Here's what I've tried:

```
"msg /server:" & hostname & " * /v /time:3600 ""my message here"""
"cmd.exe /D /c msg /server:" & hostname & " * /v /time:3600 ""my message here"""
```

Neither seems to work. I know the registry value is being changed. I put message boxes after each step in my and refreshed the regedit to actually see the value of the DWORD key, and it is changing. Everything APPEARS to be going smoothly, the message is just not getting sent.

I do have these commands running as arguments to a function I created in order to create a process so I could output the streamreader to a listbox.

Here's my code. Please keep in mind, I'm barely over 2 months into learning visual basic, so it's probably not the prettiest code out there:

```
Imports System
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Diagnostics
Imports System.Security.Permissions
Imports Microsoft.Win32

Public Class applicationMain
    Private Sub btnExecute_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExecute.Click
        Dim oldPC As String = txtOldPC.Text
        Dim newPC As String = txtNewPC.Text
        Dim username As String = txtUsername.Text
        Dim password As String = txtPassword.Text

        If oldPC <> "" And newPC <> "" And username <> "" And password <> "" Then

            Dim MyReg As Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey = Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.OpenRemoteBaseKey(Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive.LocalMachine, oldPC)
            Dim MyRegKey As Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey
            Dim MyVal As String

            lbOutput.Items.Clear()

            MyRegKey = MyReg.OpenSubKey("System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server")
            MyVal = MyRegKey.GetValue("AllowRemoteRPC", RegistryValueKind.DWord)
            MyRegKey.Close()

            lbOutput.Items.Add("Processing registry changes...")

            Try
                MyRegKey = MyReg.OpenSubKey("System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server", True)
                MyRegKey.SetValue("AllowRemoteRPC", &H1, RegistryValueKind.DWord)
            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show("An Error Has Occured:" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & ex.ToString())
                lbOutput.Items.Add("")
                lbOutput.Items.Add("ABORTED!")
                Exit Sub
            End Try

            lbOutput.Items.Add("Success!")
            lbOutput.Items.Add("Sending message to user:")

            Try
                ExecuteCommand("cmd.exe", "/D /c msg /SERVER:" & oldPC & ".na.int.grp * /v /TIME:3600 ""Changes have been made by IS to your computer that require a restart. Please save your files and restart your computer to avoid service interruption.""")
            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show("An Error Has Occured:" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & ex.ToString())
                lbOutput.Items.Add("")
                lbOutput.Items.Add("ABORTED!")
                MyRegKey = MyReg.OpenSubKey("System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server", True)
                MyRegKey.SetValue("AllowRemoteRPC", MyVal, RegistryValueKind.DWord)
                Exit Sub
            End Try

            lbOutput.Items.Add("   Message: ""Changes have been made by IS to your computer that require a restart. Please save your files and restart your computer to avoid service interruption."" ")

            lbOutput.Items.Add("Reverting registry changes...")

            Try
                MyRegKey = MyReg.OpenSubKey("System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server", True)
                MyRegKey.SetValue("AllowRemoteRPC", MyVal, RegistryValueKind.DWord)
            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show("An Error Has Occured:" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & ex.ToString())
                lbOutput.Items.Add("")
                lbOutput.Items.Add("ABORTED!")
                Exit Sub
            End Try

            Try
                ExecuteCommand("netdom", "renamecomputer " & oldPC & " /newname:" & newPC & " /userD:na\" & username & " /passwordd:" & password & " /usero:na\" & username & " /passwordo:" & password & " /Force")
            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show("An Error Has Occured:" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & ex.ToString())
                lbOutput.Items.Add("")
                lbOutput.Items.Add("ABORTED!")
                Exit Sub
            End Try


            lbOutput.Items.Add("Success!")
            lbOutput.Items.Add("")


            lbOutput.Items.Add("Rename successful for " & oldPC & "!")
            lbOutput.Items.Add("******************************************************************")
            lbOutput.Items.Add("")

        End If
    End Sub
    Private Function ExecuteCommand(ByVal cmd As String, ByVal arguments As String)

        Dim cmdProcess As New Process()
        Dim cmdProcessStartInfo As New ProcessStartInfo()
        Dim cmdStreamReader As IO.StreamReader
        Dim output As String

        cmdProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
        cmdProcessStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
        cmdProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True

        cmdProcessStartInfo.FileName = cmd
        cmdProcessStartInfo.Arguments = arguments
        cmdProcess.StartInfo = cmdProcessStartInfo

        cmdProcess.Start()
        cmdStreamReader = cmdProcess.StandardOutput

        Do While cmdStreamReader.EndOfStream = False
            output = cmdStreamReader.ReadLine()
            lbOutput.SelectedIndex = lbOutput.Items.Count - 1
            lbOutput.Items.Add(output)
        Loop

        cmdProcess.WaitForExit()
        cmdProcess.Close()

        Return vbNull

    End Function

End Class
```

Comment: It's most likely something wrong with your command string, possibly a missing quote or space. What does the full command string look like when ran? You can also try something simpler first, like just start `NOTEPAD.EXE` to make sure you can even run anything.

Comment: I am running netdom commands using `ExecuteCommand("netdom","renamecomputer " & oldPC & " /newname:" & newPC & " /userD:domain\" & username & " /passwordd:" & password & "usero:domain\" & username & " /passwordo:" & password & " /Force")` as well as ping using `ExecuteCommand("cmd.exe", "/D /c ping " & oldPC`. I get you're saying my structure is probably wrong, but I've tried every variation of `"msg","arguments-here"` and `"cmd.exe","/D /c msg arguments-here"` I can think of. Hoping others might have some suggestions. Run from a cmd window, I can send a message all day long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you know. There's actually nothing wrong with my code at all. While trying to play around with the paths variable, I decided "Fuhgeddaboudit, I'll just add the executable to the project!". Right clicked the project, Add -> Existing Item. Selected Executable as the type, and went to C:\Windows\System32 and, get this now, **msg.exe wasn't there**. At all. Opened Explorer and went to System32, msg.exe was there. For whatever reason, Visual Studio cannot see the program at all. Which is in and of itself weird.

So I copied msg.exe to my desktop, added it to source, the program works like a charm now.